# Proper menumonic for wirting out a 4th order tensor components

Tags: matrices, notation, tensors

I am getting my feet wet with material properties which are typically represented by 4th order tensors. I like to write out stuff in long form when first until I get the intuition to take short cuts. So in writing something out like $ C_{ijkl} $  I get lost working with the 4 sets of indices. I am starting with the isotropic tensor which has a paticular form $$\textbf{C} = \lambda\delta_{ij}\delta_{kl} + \mu(\delta_{ik}\delta_{jl}+ \delta_{li}\delta_{jk})$$

I have googled a bit and I have found the [following](https://csmbrannon.net/2015/08/10/fourth-order-tensor-tutorial-excerpts-voigt-and-mandel-representations-as-well-as-isotropy-topics/) which has the answer I am looking for but I am trying to map out the convention used to generate that big tensor. Wikipedia and a few other books cite the following

1. Write down the second order tensor in matrix form (in the example, the stress tensor)
2. Strike out the diagonal
3. Continue on the third column
4. Go back to the first element along the first row.

Following these rules will not give me the tensor in the link I would get the following for the top row $$c_{1111},c_{1122},c_{1133},c_{1123},c_{1113},c_{1112},?$$

So I am short the final three terms and the order is not correct after the 4th term. Now I know these are symmetric tensors and I could just change the orders of the indices but I am worried in other scenarios where my inability to work through layout of a higher order tensor may be problematic.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Your formula for the isotropic tensor $C$ already tells you what every "entry" of the tensor is. So to write them out, you just ... write them out? The formula says $c_{ijk\ell}$ is $0$ unless $ijk\ell$ is two pairs of distinct indices, in which case either $i=j\ne k=\ell$ and $c_{ijk\ell}=\lambda$ else $c_{ijk\ell}=\mu$. I guess there's a question of literally how to arrange the various numbers on paper (or screen), but still. Dunno how to interpret your four rules or what they're supposed to do.  So I really don't feel like I understand your question.

Comment: @runway44 Yes this is more about how to arrange the values. In various books they have specific order so one can see planes of symmetry and stuff based on how the non-zero elements are arranged. I would like to be able to write this out without memorization. There must be some rule to it but I am not sure what that rule is. Thank you for the comment thought!

Comment: I mean, you could write it as a matrix of matrices, as long as you're careful to tell where one matrix begins and another ends. I think there's only so much symmetry you can tell by looking at the numbers in any particular arrangement, and that it's better or more feasible to see the symmetry in the formulas for or characteristics of the tensors.